How to implement the transition between windows, save the input data in the first two windows for further use in the main third window?
There is a file __init__.py in which I want to create a list that will have to accept data from two other files.
First, the __init__.py runs the first file in which the user enters some data.
Then he clicks "continue" and the first window closes, and a new one opens, in which he does the same thing, but after clicking on the "start" button, the second window closes, and in the file __init__.py there is a list that consists of previously entered data in these two windows.
I implemented data collection from lineEdit into an array, but I can't figure out how to combine them and transfer them to the initial file?
How can this be implemented?
authorization.py:

import sys

from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

from src.ui.py.OST_authorization import Ui_OST_authorization


class Authorization(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.ui = Ui_OST_authorization()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.Continue.clicked.connect(self.student_data)
        self.show()

    def student_data(self) -> dict:
        return {"Имя": self.ui.Name.text(), "Фамилия": self.ui.Surname.text(), "Отчество": self.ui.Patronymic.text(),
                "Номер и буква класса": self.ui.Class.text(), "Серия": self.ui.Series.text(),
                "Номер": self.ui.Number.text()}


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    authorization_window = Authorization()
    sys.exit(app.exec())

OST_authorization.py:
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_OST_authorization(object):
    def setupUi(self, OST_authorization):
        OST_authorization.setObjectName("OST_authorization")
        OST_authorization.resize(330, 381)
        OST_authorization.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(330, 381))
        OST_authorization.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(330, 395))
        OST_authorization.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit#Name{\n"
"    min-width:  310px;\n"
"    min-height: 33px;\n"
"    max-width:  310px;\n"
"    max-height: 33px;\n"
"}\n"
"QLineEdit#Surname{\n"
"    min-width:  310px;\n"
"    min-height: 33px;\n"
"    max-width:  310px;\n"
"    max-height: 33px;\n"
"}\n"
"QLineEdit#Patronymic{\n"
"    min-width:  310px;\n"
"    min-height: 33px;\n"
"    max-width:  310px;\n"
"    max-height: 33px;\n"
"}\n"
"QLineEdit#Class{\n"
"    min-width:  310px;\n"
"    min-height: 33px;\n"
"    max-width:  310px;\n"
"    max-height: 33px;\n"
"}\n"
"QLineEdit#Series{\n"
"    min-width:  310px;\n"
"    min-height: 33px;\n"
"    max-width:  310px;\n"
"    max-height: 33px;\n"
"}\n"
"QLineEdit#Number{\n"
"    min-width:  310px;\n"
"    min-height: 33px;\n"
"    max-width:  310px;\n"
"    max-height: 33px;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton#Continue{\n"
"    min-width:  310px;\n"
"    min-height: 33px;\n"
"    max-width:  310px;\n"
"    max-height: 33px;\n"
"}\n"
"")
        OST_authorization.setDocumentMode(True)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(parent=OST_authorization)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.Name = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.Name.setEnabled(True)
        self.Name.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(312, 35))
        self.Name.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(312, 35))
        self.Name.setStyleSheet("")
        self.Name.setObjectName("Name")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.Name, 5, 0, 1, 2)
        self.AuthorizationLable = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.AuthorizationLable.setObjectName("AuthorizationLable")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.AuthorizationLable, 4, 0, 1, 2)
        self.line = QtWidgets.QFrame(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.line.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Shape.HLine)
        self.line.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Shadow.Sunken)
        self.line.setObjectName("line")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.line, 8, 0, 1, 2)
        self.Class = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.Class.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(312, 35))
        self.Class.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(312, 35))
        self.Class.setObjectName("Class")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.Class, 9, 0, 1, 2)
        self.line_2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.line_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Shape.HLine)
        self.line_2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Shadow.Sunken)
        self.line_2.setObjectName("line_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.line_2, 10, 0, 1, 2)
        self.Series = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.Series.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(312, 35))
        self.Series.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(312, 35))
        self.Series.setObjectName("Series")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.Series, 11, 0, 1, 2)
        self.Continue = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.Continue.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(312, 35))
        self.Continue.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(312, 35))
        self.Continue.setObjectName("Continue")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.Continue, 14, 0, 1, 2)
        self.line_3 = QtWidgets.QFrame(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.line_3.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Shape.HLine)
        self.line_3.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Shadow.Sunken)
        self.line_3.setObjectName("line_3")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.line_3, 13, 0, 1, 2)
        self.Patronymic = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.Patronymic.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(312, 35))
        self.Patronymic.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(312, 35))
        self.Patronymic.setObjectName("Patronymic")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.Patronymic, 7, 0, 1, 2)
        self.Surname = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.Surname.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(312, 35))
        self.Surname.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(312, 35))
        self.Surname.setObjectName("Surname")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.Surname, 6, 0, 1, 2)
        self.Number = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.Number.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(312, 35))
        self.Number.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(312, 35))
        self.Number.setObjectName("Number")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.Number, 12, 0, 1, 2)
        OST_authorization.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(parent=OST_authorization)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 330, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        OST_authorization.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(parent=OST_authorization)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        OST_authorization.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(OST_authorization)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(OST_authorization)

    def retranslateUi(self, OST_authorization):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        OST_authorization.setWindowTitle(_translate("OST_authorization", "OST - (демо версия)"))
        self.Name.setPlaceholderText(_translate("OST_authorization", "Имя"))
        self.AuthorizationLable.setText(_translate("OST_authorization", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" font-size:12pt;\">Авторизация</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.Class.setPlaceholderText(_translate("OST_authorization", "Номер и буква класса"))
        self.Series.setPlaceholderText(_translate("OST_authorization", "Серия"))
        self.Continue.setText(_translate("OST_authorization", "Продолжить"))
        self.Patronymic.setPlaceholderText(_translate("OST_authorization", "Отчество (при наличии)"))
        self.Surname.setPlaceholderText(_translate("OST_authorization", "Фамилия"))
        self.Number.setPlaceholderText(_translate("OST_authorization", "Номер"))

task_settings.py:
import sys

from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

from src.ui.py.OST_task_settings import Ui_OST_task_settings


class TaskSettings(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.ui = Ui_OST_task_settings()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.Start.clicked.connect(self.settings_data)

        self.show()

    def settings_data(self) -> dict:
        return {"Код образовательной организации": self.ui.CodeEducationalOrganization.text(),
                "Код ППЭ": self.ui.PPECode.text(), "Номер компьютера": self.ui.NumberPC.text(),
                "Номер варианта": self.ui.NumberPC.text(), "Код активации": self.ui.CodeActivation.text()}


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    task_settings_window = TaskSettings()
    sys.exit(app.exec())

OST_task_settings.py:
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_OST_task_settings(object):
    def setupUi(self, OST_task_settings):
        OST_task_settings.setObjectName("OST_task_settings")
        OST_task_settings.resize(330, 381)
        OST_task_settings.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(330, 381))
        OST_task_settings.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(330, 395))
        OST_task_settings.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit#NumberOption{\n"
"    min-width:  310px;\n"
"    min-height: 33px;\n"
"    max-width:  310px;\n"
"    max-height: 33px;\n"
"}\n"
"QComboBox#SettingsOption{\n"
"    min-width:  310px;\n"
"    min-height: 33px;\n"
"    max-width:  310px;\n"
"    max-height: 33px;\n"
"}\n"
"QLineEdit#CodeActivation{\n"
"    min-width:  310px;\n"
"    min-height: 33px;\n"
"    max-width:  310px;\n"
"    max-height: 33px;\n"
"}\n"
"QLineEdit#CodeEducationalOrganization{\n"
"    min-width:  310px;\n"
"    min-height: 33px;\n"
"    max-width:  310px;\n"
"    max-height: 33px;\n"
"}\n"
"QLineEdit#NumberPC{\n"
"    min-width:  310px;\n"
"    min-height: 33px;\n"
"    max-width:  310px;\n"
"    max-height: 33px;\n"
"}\n"
"QLineEdit#PPECode{\n"
"    min-width:  310px;\n"
"    min-height: 33px;\n"
"    max-width:  310px;\n"
"    max-height: 33px;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton#Start{\n"
"    min-width:  310px;\n"
"    min-height: 33px;\n"
"    max-width:  310px;\n"
"    max-height: 33px;\n"
"}")
        OST_task_settings.setDocumentMode(True)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(parent=OST_task_settings)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.Start = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.Start.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(312, 35))
        self.Start.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(312, 35))
        self.Start.setObjectName("Start")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.Start, 10, 0, 1, 1)
        self.line_2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.line_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Shape.HLine)
        self.line_2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Shadow.Sunken)
        self.line_2.setObjectName("line_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.line_2, 9, 0, 1, 1)
        self.line = QtWidgets.QFrame(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.line.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Shape.HLine)
        self.line.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Shadow.Sunken)
        self.line.setObjectName("line")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.line, 7, 0, 1, 1)
        self.NumberOption = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.NumberOption.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(312, 35))
        self.NumberOption.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(312, 35))
        self.NumberOption.setObjectName("NumberOption")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.NumberOption, 5, 0, 1, 1)
        self.line_3 = QtWidgets.QFrame(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.line_3.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Shape.HLine)
        self.line_3.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Shadow.Sunken)
        self.line_3.setObjectName("line_3")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.line_3, 4, 0, 1, 1)
        self.CodeActivation = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.CodeActivation.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(312, 35))
        self.CodeActivation.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(312, 35))
        self.CodeActivation.setObjectName("CodeActivation")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.CodeActivation, 8, 0, 1, 1)
        self.SettingsOption = QtWidgets.QComboBox(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.SettingsOption.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(312, 35))
        self.SettingsOption.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(312, 35))
        self.SettingsOption.setObjectName("SettingsOption")
        self.SettingsOption.addItem("")
        self.SettingsOption.addItem("")
        self.SettingsOption.addItem("")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.SettingsOption, 6, 0, 1, 1)
        self.PPECode = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.PPECode.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(312, 35))
        self.PPECode.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(312, 35))
        self.PPECode.setObjectName("PPECode")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.PPECode, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.NumberPC = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.NumberPC.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(312, 35))
        self.NumberPC.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(312, 35))
        self.NumberPC.setObjectName("NumberPC")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.NumberPC, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        self.CodeEducationalOrganization = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.CodeEducationalOrganization.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(312, 35))
        self.CodeEducationalOrganization.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(312, 35))
        self.CodeEducationalOrganization.setObjectName("CodeEducationalOrganization")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.CodeEducationalOrganization, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        OST_task_settings.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(parent=OST_task_settings)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 330, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        OST_task_settings.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(parent=OST_task_settings)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        OST_task_settings.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(OST_task_settings)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(OST_task_settings)

    def retranslateUi(self, OST_task_settings):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        OST_task_settings.setWindowTitle(_translate("OST_task_settings", "OST - (демо версия)"))
        self.Start.setText(_translate("OST_task_settings", "Начать"))
        self.NumberOption.setPlaceholderText(_translate("OST_task_settings", "Номер варианта"))
        self.CodeActivation.setPlaceholderText(_translate("OST_task_settings", "Код активации"))
        self.SettingsOption.setItemText(0, _translate("OST_task_settings", "[Без дополнений]"))
        self.SettingsOption.setItemText(1, _translate("OST_task_settings", "Случайный вариант"))
        self.SettingsOption.setItemText(2, _translate("OST_task_settings", "Составить вариант"))
        self.PPECode.setPlaceholderText(_translate("OST_task_settings", "Код ППЭ"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("OST_task_settings", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" font-size:12pt;\">Дополнительные данные</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.NumberPC.setPlaceholderText(_translate("OST_task_settings", "Номер компьютера"))
        self.CodeEducationalOrganization.setPlaceholderText(_translate("OST_task_settings", "Код образовательной организации"))`

